# Variable in subquery from main query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get `USER_FNM` (user's first name) from table BAUSER for each `USER_KEY`. Return result from my query however shows only `USER_FNM` from the first in the table - Superadministrator. I don't know what is wrong - is `USER_KEY` iterating in subquery or not?

Here is query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT USER_KEY, (SELECT TOP(1) USER_FNM FROM BAUSER WHERE BAUSER.USER_KEY = USER_KEY), SUM([110000003]),SUM([120000002]),SUM([120000003])
FROM CAUSDE_TAS CA
PIVOT
(
SUM(USDE_HSU)
FOR DEPA_KEY IN ([110000003],[120000002],[120000003]
) PIVOT_LOCATIONS
WHERE USDE_DAT >= '01.12.2016' AND USDE_DAT <= '03.02.2017' 
AND USER_KEY IN (100000002,100000004,100000006,100000008,100000011)
GROUP BY USER_KEY
```

And here are results:

[image]

Comment: the reason behind this behaviour is that USER_KEY as a column is present both in BAUSER table and in the PIVOT_LOCATIONS result table. Most probably the SQL query optimizer read the closes USER_KEY which is BAUSER.USER_KEY so it ends up with BAUSER.USER_KEY=BAUSER.USER_KEY, which returns all rows from BAUSER table. Afterwards we have TOP(1) which just returns the first record (which apparently is "Suporadministrator"). This query should work fine without the TOP(1) clause because I guess USER_KEY is unique. By removing TOP(1) the faulty logic will immediately pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PIVOT_LOCATIONS.USER_KEY in your subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT USER_KEY, (SELECT TOP(1) USER_FNM FROM BAUSER WHERE BAUSER.USER_KEY = PIVOT_LOCATIONS.USER_KEY), SUM([110000003]),SUM([120000002]),SUM([120000003])
    FROM CAUSDE_TAS CA
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(USDE_HSU)
    FOR DEPA_KEY IN ([110000003],[120000002],[120000003]
    ) PIVOT_LOCATIONS
    WHERE USDE_DAT >= '01.12.2016' AND USDE_DAT <= '03.02.2017' 
    AND USER_KEY IN (100000002,100000004,100000006,100000008,100000011)
    GROUP BY USER_KEY
```

Comment: This is throwing error: The multi-part identifier "CA.USER_KEY" could not be bound.

Comment: not "CA.USER_KEY", but "PIVOT_LOCATIONS.USER_KEY" should be used instead